# How can I launch Ubuntu Variants and Betas on GCE?

Tags: cloud, 16.04

I swear the image should be up there, but I'm not finding it.  I'm also interested to know the command line commands I'd use to show absolutely all Ubuntu images on GCE.  So far I've got:

```
gcloud compute images --no-standard-images --project=ubuntu-snappy
```

...but that only lists snappy images, and isn't enough.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/linux-os#ubuntu does not list 16.04. Why would you expect an alpha version to available?

Comment: Because what? That Ubuntu's site lists an alpha image?

Comment: Well, you know, alpha images being what they're, you know, if you're going test them, it'd be reasonable to expect you know how to create an image, you know?

Comment: Why not? Whoever said you had to be using "official" images for filing bug reports? Just state that in your bug report.

Comment: then stop annoying people

Comment: considering you have shown little interest in actually solving your problems, yes, I accept the apology.

Comment: you did nothing. The problem solved itself.

Comment: That's all I have to say. Take your trolling elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly a bit late now, but here's how to do it:

Follow the steps at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/creating-custom-image#import_a_virtualbox_image. Really the only complication is finding out which of the images from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/20160418/ to chose. I finally got it working with `xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.vmdk`. I also used `vbox-img`, not `VBoxManage`, but I believe the two are identical anyway.